# Unable to span wrap html text with single or double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

**Contenteditable div**

```
var1 = 'x';
var2 = someVar
```

**Target**

```
<span class="frag">var1 = 'x'</span>;
<span class="frag">var2 = someVar</span>;
```

**JS**

```
$('#board_code_dup').children().each(function (index, child) {
   var text = $(child).html();

   //HOW TO DO THIS RIGHT?
   text = text.replace(/([A-Za-z0-9_]+\s*=\s*[A-Za-z0-9&'"]+)/g, '<span class="frag">$1</span>');
});
```

How would i use HTML entities `&quot; &apos;` here instead of `' "` so that i can properly wrap it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but to use HTML entities instead of `'` and `"`, you could use `(?:[A-Za-z0-9&]|&quot;|&apos;)` or `(?:[A-Za-z0-9&]|&(?:quot|apos);)`

Comment: You aren't creating an attribute node, so you don't need to use `&apos;` or `&quot;`. Other then that, the idea of parsing JavaScript code using regular expressions is going to fail, unless in the *very* trivial case. JavaScript source code is more expressive then what regular expressions are capable of.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've tried `"$('#board_code_dup').text()"` and split it on "\n" instead ..

It will convert entities behind the scene like quotes or double quotes in the source. This might match in reg-exp.

```
var result = $('#board_code_dup').text().split("\n").map(function (el, idx){
                    return el.replace(/\s*;\s*$/,'').replace( /(\w+\s*=\s*[\w&"']+)/g,'<span class="frag">$1</span>');
            });
alert(result.join(''));
```

Js fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AVfQz/)

I hope this will help ..